# Problems with program which find prime number from 1 to 100

Tags: c++

I wrote this program which find and displays prime numbers from 1 to 100

```
int ifprime (int n)
{
    int i=1;
    while (i<= n)
    {
        i++;
        if (n%i == 0) 
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }
        else continue;
    }
    return true;
}

int prime_numbers (void)
{
    bool result;
    for (int i = 2; i<=100; ++i)
    {
        result = ifprime(i);
        if (result==true) cout<<i<<endl;
        else continue;

    }
}

int main()
{
    prime_numbers();
    return 0;
}
```

The program displays nothing. Why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is that all of your program? Because you didn't include any `main()` function that call any of the above functions

Comment: `return; break;` is pointless. return terminates your function right then and there. that makes the `break` call dead/unreachable code.

Comment: everything is divisible by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
for(int i=2; i<n; i++){
    if(n%i==0){
         return false;
    }
}
```

Or your while end condition to:

```
while(i < n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, every non-zero number is divisible by 1 and itself. Change this line (line 4)

```
while (i<= n)
```

to

```
while (i< n)
```

Comment: You also started from 1.  So that n%1 will always be 0.

Comment: @user3813353 there's a postincrement, preincrementing

Comment: @user3813353 Good point, but `i` is initialized to `1` and incremented before the first comparison (so it's already `2` at that point).

Answer (score 1):

If that's your whole code, then you're simply missing a `main()` function.

Though it shouldn't link without a `main()` function.

There are some additional problems with your code, but that's probably the reason why you don't see any output.

Try adding this to your file:

```
int main()
{
    prime_numbers();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did and nothing happen. Do you think //int prime_numbers (void)
 make it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Many people have pointed out the problem with:

```
while (i <= n)
```

...because you allow `i` to be `n` in your for loop, every natural number is divisible by itself so it wrongly accuses prime numbers of being composites.  As people pointed out, the quick fix is:

```
while (i < n)
```

But the reason why I reply is because there are other things you can do to make your code better.  The first improvement is that you don't need to try dividing by numbers greater than the square root of `n` because if there is a greater than it, then there is also a divisor less than it.  So you could do something like this:

```
while (i*i <= n)
```

But there are further improvements you can do on that.  For example, why should you have to compute i*i every iteration?  If you pre-compute square root of `n` (rounded to int), then you can avoid that computation.

Another optimization is that you can avoid trial dividing by half of the numbers: if `n` is not divisible by 2, then no reason to try any other even numbers.  So you can jump `i` by 2 every time in your inner loop.  There are other tricks if you want to eliminate trial dividing by numbers divisible by 3.

Really, however, there is a nice super-duper fast algorithm to find the first `x` primes if you don't mind using order `x` bytes of memory.  It is called the [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), and it is really fun to implement.  Once you get your current code optimized, I recommend trying the sieve.

The problem of finding prime numbers efficiently has received an enormous amount of attention in the academic literature, and it is now considered solved.  But it takes a lot of study to learn it.